# How to use promises with AWS headObject?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Using Node AWS SDK which supports callbacks and promises..
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/support-for-promises-in-the-sdk/

Using q as promise library..
`AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(q);`

`const headObjProm = this.s3Client.headObject(headParams).promise();`

```
 headObjProm
   .then(ret => {
     //ret is promise..
   })
```

console logging `ret` shows..

```
(resolve, reject) {
   self.on('complete', function(resp) {
     if (resp.error) {
       reject(resp.error);
     } else {
       resolve(resp.data);
     }
  });
```

I was under impression `ret` would be data or error message?
The documentation on AWS is all done in callback style.
How to use this with promises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're initializing the `Q` package as the Promise to use, you need to specify the `Promise` property from `Q`.

`AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('Q').Promise);`

Answer (score 3):

Since `const headObjProm = this.s3Client.headObject(headParams).promise();` is asynchronous, how about say you have this in an async function and use await like so:

```
`const resolveHeadObject = async()=> await s3Client.headObject(headParams).promise()`
```

I use the `await/async` syntax and it works for me.

Don't forget to add `.Promise` to your `Q` require as well, if that's necessary.